# Hide extras with Javascript in Photoshop

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop

Is there any way to hide extras (specifically the selection/marching ants) using Javascript in photoshop? I have an action that I frequently use to make a selection, and inevitably always follow it up with Cmd + H to hide the selection. Curious if there's a way with a script I could reduce three keystrokes to just one. I've spent a while googling and it seems like it might not be possible, but I also didn't find anyone asking this specific question. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggling Extras (Cmd + H) can be scripted the following way:

```
app.runMenuItem (app.stringIDToTypeID ("toggleShowExtras"));
```

If you prefer to include this step in an action you're currently recording, don't directly select the View > Extra command, but use "Insert Menu Item..." from the contextual menu located at the upper right of the Actions palette/panel, then select the command while the dialog is displayed and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there is no way either via scriptlistener or JavaScript to do that.

```
// this is pseudo code
activeDocument.selection.selectAll().show(false);
// this doesn't work
```

There are few things that are beyond the scope of Photoshop scripting and that is (sadly) show extras is one of them. But by all means prove me wrong.